# Best way to create custom method security expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm trying to create my own method security expressions, that I want to use in `@PreFilter` and `@PostFilter` annotations.

Searching for tutorials and similar questions I've found two ways to proceed.

The first is to extend `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` and override `createSecurityExpressionRoot`, in order to give a customized `SecurityExpressionRoot`.

```
@PreAuthorize('isOwner(#someEntity)')
```

The second way is to simply use a @Component class and in `@Pre` / `@Post` filter accessing its methods with `@bean.method()`

```
@PreAuthorize("@mySecurityService.isOwner('#someEntityl')")
```

My question is: Which is the preferred way? If both are ok, why choose one ore another?

thank you
Marco

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Advantages of `@PreAuthorize('isOwner(#someEntity)')` way over `@bean.method()` way:

- From maintenance point of view: when you change signature of some method like `CustomSecurityExpressionRoot.isOwner()` then it is clear for you (and even for some new developer familiar with Spring Security) that you need to review all `@Pre` / `@Post` annotations. This advantage is not so important if you have JUnit tests for all `@Pre` / `@Post` cases.
- Short syntax (you can try some short alias to improve `@bean.method()` way, for example `@sec.isOwner()`)
- With `SecurityExpressionRoot` you automatically have access to `authentication`, `trustResolver`, `roles`, `permissionEvaluator` ojects. It is not so important because you can easy get them in your custom bean too.

Advantages of `@bean.method()` way over `@PreAuthorize('isOwner(#someEntity)')` way:

- Easy setup

I am like your `@bean.method()` way. IMHO all differences are not so important (for my previous project). But I like "easy setup" option so much! So for next project I'll try your `@bean.method()` way in conjuction with JUnit tests for all `@Pre` / `@Post` cases.