# spring security method security at run-time and dynamically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

If I have a controller method

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/boards/{id}")
public String viewBoard(@PathVariable(value="id") String id){/*..*/}
```

How can I dynamically, at `run-time`, `pre authorize` the user for it by querying the `database` and getting the desired value for that board id access (for the logged in user).

I tried to research on `runtime dynamic` spring security permissions with spring security roles but **couldnt find a working example.**

---

**Further elaboration:**

It means, every time the user wants to access that method, the database is checked that whether the user has permissions for it.

**This cannot be done in `roles` as there might be millions of cases.** e.g. one user may have view access for a board id 3 but not for board id 10003

---

**some links I got:**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-method-security

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

http://www.javabeat.net/separating-roles-and-permissions-in-spring-security/

---

**Further info:**

I am using `public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{` to give users Roles at login time. But thats a different story.

Comment: You can create custom filter that intercepts all requests to filter dynamicaly

Comment: Take a look here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803406/best-way-to-create-custom-method-security-expression. If you feel that this post can be useful and it cuold be what you need, I can give you more details and elaborate an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend spring security to provide your own expressions: next to `hasRole`

See this question for an example: [How to create custom methods for use in spring security expression language annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno)

*One important point when looking for examples: pay attention that the example is for the METHOD-Resolver, not for the WEB-Resolver!*