# Custom method within spring @Preauthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am implementing an application which has some methods to which's access will be fully based on permissions. The permissions are implemented using Spring. The permissions are added using **@PreAuthorize** annotation on top of the methods. The problem is that I would like to have fully custom methods (EL) within the annotations. 
So what I would like to achieve is for instance:

```
@PreAuthorize("customAllowThis()")
public void foo() { }
```

I think there are two approaches:

Approach 1:
Try to override **SecurityExpressionRoot** and add my custom methods there. I will use multiple authorisation services on different methods, so putting all specific methods to SecurityExpressionRoot would be a big chaos.

Approach 2:
Create service and place the method there:

```
@Component
public class AuthorisationService {
    public boolean allowThis() {
         return true;
    }
}
```

and do something like:

```
@PreAuthorize("@authorisationService.customAllowThis()")
public void foo() { }
```

I much more prefer Approach 2 although it looks for me like it would bypass the "natural order" of Spring. Are there any good/best practices in terms of how to handle such situation? The point is that I wouldn't like to stick all specific methods into one class but from the other hand I wouldn't like to do something "dirty".

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632982/how-to-create-custom-methods-for-use-in-spring-security-expression-language-anno?rq=1

Comment: Hey I have seen this, but one person says its not possible in Spring 3.x and there is another comment where guy just does that.. I am a bit confused.!

Comment: You try something? or you are asking only for best practiques?

Comment: Just asking for best practices..

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803406/best-way-to-create-custom-method-security-expression

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you can do the following :

1. Create a custom annotation that accepts an array of allowed roles, something like this :

   @Allows({RoleEnum.ROLE1, RoleEnum.ROLE2 })
2. using SPeL, we can invoke a custom method that will check if the user has these Roles, something like this :

   @PreAuthorize("myServiceClass.hasRoles(#roles)")
3. in the service class, you can just validate the user roles against the roles from OAuth database, and perform any business logic in the service.

Comment: Can you show some more code? How does the `@PreAuthorize` access the roles in the other annotation? I've been trying to figure out how to do that.